# Trying to download only specific files from FTP folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found some code online which downloads all files from a FTP folder.  I want to modify the code, just slightly, to download only files that match a certain naming convention.  For instance, I want to download only files that have 'ARM' in the name.  I think the code below is close, but I'm getting an error message that reads:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

The error occurs on this line:  `if file in 'ARM':`

Here is a sample of my code (this is not all the code; just trying to keep it simple).

```
for file in filelist:
    if file in 'ARM':
        if file[1]['type'] == 'file':
            fullpath = os.path.join(destination[:-1] + path, file[0])
            if (not overwrite and os.path.isfile(fullpath)):
                continue
            else:
                with open(fullpath, 'wb') as f:
                    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + file[0], f.write)
                print(file[0] + '  downloaded')
        elif file[1]['type'] == 'dir':
            fetchFiles(ftp, path + file[0] + '/', destination, overwrite)
    else:
        print('Unknown type: ' + file[1]['type'])
```

I guess I need to loop through the elements of a Tuple.  Is that right?  Can I simply check the name of the file to find matching strings?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `if 'ARM' in file` instead? That tests what you describe. Also: where does `filelist` come from? What is its value when you print it?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I had it backwards.  This works:  if 'ARM' in str(file):
Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Sure -- but be careful! Your `str(file)` converts your entire tuple (apparently it is one) to a string. Better inspect `filelist` and pick only the item you are interested it.

Comment: It would probably help if you include how you got your `filelist`. If it returns a list of tuples, with a predefined meaning for each element, you can do `for item1,item2,item3 in filelist` and have each tuple element assigned to a named variable.

Comment: Everything works fine now.  Thanks usr2564301!!